# Pass credentials from ASP.NET to IIS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, iis-10

I have one machine running IIS10, another machine running SQL Server Express. I have create an ASP.NET Razor pages web application. All machines are Windows 10 pro.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to take the credentials from the web app, pass to IIS, and pass to SQL Server. I want to manager access to SQL Server at the user level, not the IIS `DefaultAppPool` identity.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: So you want to have a separate SQL Server user for every user of your web application? This sounds like a nightmare to maintain. What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I think the technique you are looking for is called impersonation. If IIS and SQL Server are running on seperate machines then you may also need to configure Kerberos.

Comment: Did you try `impersonation`?

Comment: Approaches like that are no longer common practice to use database (consider the cloud computing scenarios). Though if you insist, check out ASP.NET user impersonation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to pass the user's network login to the database instead of using a dedicated DB account? I think you need a trusted connection.

1. Grant your users access to your DB
2. Disable anonymous access in IIS and set the site up SSL
3. In your connection string set the Trusted_Connection property to true

[Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

If the user is on any browser except IE, they'll probably be prompted for their credentials.